# disabling a submit button, is disabling the form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I am experiencing something very strange. When a form is submitted, I am disabling the `submit` button with the following code:

```
$(btn).addClass('sbmt_disable').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

However, the effect it creates is it appears to just reload the page, and the fields are empty. Is it not possible to submit a form, if the submit button is disabled then? If so, what is the alternative? The desired action is to prevent users from clicking on the form more than once.

Comment: Are you doing it onsubmit or onclick?

Comment: doing it onclick `$('#contact_btn').click(function(e){....`

Comment: well there is your problem.... if you did it onsubmit of the form, you would not have issues.Disabling the button on click cancels the click.

Comment: no, that still didnt work, the form still doesnt submit `$('#contact_form').submit(function(e){...`

Comment: Than delay it with a timeout `setTimeout(()=>{foo.disabled=true},1) `or use pointer events in css to disable it.